# Getting a category list to stay displayed on my drop down menu

Tags: javascript

Everything works great here but What I'm trying to do is have the list under the Rock category stay displayed until you click on the blues category. I want the Rock category to start off being displayed until another category link is clicked on. Any help would be appreciated since i'm new to javascript. Here is my code and Please see demo...

http://jsfiddle.net/davidzupec/2BTkL/2/

```
$(function () {
$('a').bind('click',function () {
    var Class = $(this).attr('class');

    var ulName = 'ul.' + Class;
    var Display=$(ulName).css('display');
    var Dis = $(ulName).css('display');

    $(ulName).siblings().hide();
    if (Dis == "block" || Dis == "undefined") {
        $(ulName).slideUp();
    }
    else {
        $(ulName).slideDown().show(1);
    }

})
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you want something like this?

```
$(function () {
    $('a').bind('click',function () {
        var Class = $(this).attr('class');
        var ulName = 'ul.' + Class;
        var Dis = $(ulName).css('display');

        $(ulName).siblings().hide();
        if (Dis == "block" || Dis == "undefined") {
            //$(ulName).slideUp();
        }
        else {
            $(ulName).slideDown();
        }
    });
    $(".rock").show()
});
```

Comment: Hi Gert, this seems to work great! Is there a way to add a class selected so that the Rock link will be highlighted as well?

Comment: Can you give me highlight example? I don't know much about jquery, I can only puzzle things together :)

Comment: I just figured that one out : ) Thanks again Gert for your help, your code worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to set rock to be displayed in CSS:

```
ul.rock {
    display:block;
}
```